# Trying to expose an endpoint from a kubernetes pod to the internet/ browser/ API

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

### What am I trying to do

Trying to expose an endpoint from a kubernetes pod to the internet/ browser/ API on a Windows 11 platform with WSL 2 enabled and using Powershell, Docker on Windows, kubectl and minikube. This is essential for resolving my dev environment.

### What happens

Based on whatever I could find in the docs and online, I saw Loadbalancer as the option used for <>. The tunneling never seemed to happen. I tested using the browser and using curl.

### Environment Information

- Windows: Windows 11 Pro
- Docker on Windows: Docker Desktop 4.3.2 (72729)
- Kubernetes: v1.22.3
- Minikube: minikube version: v1.24.0

### Commands - executed

Here are the commands that I executed to create the service.

##### 1. Create the deployment

```
~ kubectl create deployment hello-world3 --image=nginx:mainline-alpine
deployment.apps/hello-world3 created

~ kubectl get deployment
NAME           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
hello-world3   1/1     1            1           19s
```

##### 2. Expose outbound

```
~ kubectl expose deployment hello-world3 --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
service/hello-world3 exposed

~ kubectl get svc
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
hello-world3   LoadBalancer   10.103.203.156   127.0.0.1     8080:30300/TCP   14s
kubernetes     ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          6d8h
```

##### 3.  Create tunnel service

```
~ minikube service hello-world3
|-----------|--------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |     NAME     | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|--------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | hello-world3 |        8080 | http://192.168.49.2:30300 |
|-----------|--------------|-------------|---------------------------|
* Starting tunnel for service hello-world3.
|-----------|--------------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |     NAME     | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|--------------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | hello-world3 |             | http://127.0.0.1:62864 |
|-----------|--------------|-------------|------------------------|
* Opening service default/hello-world3 in default browser...
! Because you are using a Docker driver on windows, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

I expected to get the “Nginx welcome” page when I connect to http://127.0.0.1:8080

But it was

> This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset.
> Try:
> Checking the connection
> Checking the proxy and the firewall
> Running Windows Network Diagnostics
> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Same occurs with:
http://127.0.0.1:62864/

#### Output when I use curl

```
~ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/* -v
VERBOSE: GET with 0-byte payload
curl : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/ -v
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

```
~ curl http://127.0.0.1:62864/ -v
VERBOSE: GET with 0-byte payload
curl : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://127.0.0.1:62864/ -v
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: It is very hard to determine, what you have done and what are just comments. Can you improve your question? Have look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I've tried clarify my question and improved the edit.  Hopefully reads better

Comment: I edited your question. Try to use the code- and quote-blocks next time. :)

Comment: Look like your web service (nginx) is listening on port 80 (within kubernetes as this is default). Yet your port mapping appears to be 8080:30300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-world3 --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
```

You can check what happened when you used command above using `kubectl get svc hello-world3 -o yaml` and look on ports section:

```
ports:
- nodePort: 30514
  port:8080
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort:8080
```

As you can see `targetPort` has been set to the same port as `port`. You can read more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service)

> Note: A Service can map any incoming port to a targetPort. By default and for convenience, the targetPort is set to the same value as the port field.

You couldn't see nginx page because `targetPort` should be set to `80` which is listening by pods by default instead of `8080`.

To solve your issue you can set a `targetPort` to port `80` , by adding `--target-port=80` to your command as below:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-world3 --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080 --target-port=80
```

---

More convenient option using Kubernetes on Windows machine is set up `Enable Kubernetes` option in Docker Desktop in `Settings>Kubernetes`. Cluster will be created automatically and you will be able use `kubectl` commands in few minutes in terminal or powershell. If something goes wrong, you will be able easily reset your cluster by clicking     `Reset Kubernetes Cluster` button which is in the same place when you enabled Kubernetes in Docker Desktop.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It works.  Much appreciate your patient explanation :).  Will read up the links that you have provided.

Comment: It worked perfectly well and many thanks - saved a lot of time.  The kubernetes document is great - but in this case, may have been useful if they had indicated that an explicit use of a different targetPort - listening port  would help with port conflict issues in some circumstances.